# Супер какой частью речи является?

Tags: морфология, части-речи

Слово *супер* — это какая часть речи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Все ответы в словаре** (пользуйтесь словарями на Грамоте.ру):

[http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=супер&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80&all=x)

Это **существительное** (=суперобложка), а также употребляется в значении  **прилагательного и  наречия**, а также **приставка в сложных словах**.

СУПЕР. Разг. I. -а; м. =Суперобложка. Книга в супере. Красочный с. II. неизм.; в зн. прил. Отличный, очень хороший, превосходный. У него джинсы просто с. III. в зн. нареч. Отлично, очень хорошо, превосходно. Как дела? - С.!

СУПЕР... [от лат. super - над, выше] Первая часть сложных слов...